# Is there a word for a style of art that is a great example of its own style? And a word that can be applied to its artist?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

I was mainly thinking about musical artists whose songs have style that is very recognizable as an "artists name" song or as a specific genres song. Not a super pressing question but just something that I am curious about.

Comment: I think the answers you have a better, but there is also _paradigm_.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you're looking for ***quintessential*** (adj).

Defined by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/quintessential):

> Quintessential means representing a perfect or typical example of something.
> [formal]
> *Everybody thinks of him as the quintessential New Yorker.*

There is also ***archetypal***:

Defined by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/archetypal)

> Someone or something that is archetypal has all the most important characteristics of a particular kind of person or thing and is a perfect example of it.

Comment: _trademark_ is another word, right?

Comment: @user405662 - That’s true. “That’s trademark Hendrix right there.”

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be looking for **iconic**.

> **iconic** *adj*
>
> 2. Symbolic, emblematic, or representative: *a classroom scene that is iconic of what is wrong with the education system.*
>    <sub>[TFD Online](https://thefreeductionary.com/iconic)</sub>

For example,

> Picasso is the iconic example of the Cubist movement in 20th century art.

Comment: Too funny.  I was going to use Picasso and Cubist as an example too, but I got sidetracked.

Answer (score 1):

**Exemplary**

> When something is the best it can be or reaches the highest point, it
> is exemplary and thus worth imitating. Exemplary comes from the Latin
> exemplum, meaning "sample" or "example." While some people and things
> are held as examples of what not to do, an exemplary person or thing
> is always a positive example

For example,

> Banksy represents the greatest global artist of the new millennium, an
> exemplary case of popularity for a living author

Comment: And the form "he is an exemplar of this style" is also used.